# the container references non existing library

Tags: android, eclipse

Getting These errors after creating a new project -

```
The container 'android dependencies' references non existing library
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

Please help me in resolving these errors as I am new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the libs folder then right click on each .jar file and select build path then add to build path.

For v7appcompact project add both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7.jar files to build path.

This will resolve the build path errors.